# Free plagiarism checker with API

Tags: javascript, html, php, api, plagiarism-detection

I am building a plagiarism checker for my essay writing site. I am not able to find any plagiarism checker API for free, where I'll be able to send data and get the result as a percentage. I searched around the web I could find those kind of checker for paid only. Please suggest any API that I could use for free.

I have tried prepostseo, plagly, which are paid.

Recommendation using web technologies are welcomed (JavaScript, PHP, etc.) or some other API services that I could use for free.

Comment: [This list](https://www.reddit.com/r/opensource/comments/8xgldr/any_freeopensource_software_for_plagiarism/) may be a good place to start. not sure if any of them are free or have APIS though